# Missing } inserted error using tikz \matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compilation-error, tikz-matrix

My code compiles the matrix fine, but does not seem to realize it's left the matrix environment. If I try to put another matrix immediately after, I get the error "you cannot nest pgfmatrix environments (yet)". If I don't, I get the error in the title. Here is my code:

```
% my current packages, in case it matters
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns,patterns.meta}

% the actual code
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \matrix at (7, 0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw}] {
            & & & & \\
            & & & & \\
            & & & & \\
            & & & & \\
            & & & & \\
            & & & & \\
            
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the blank line after all the &&&&\\ lines and before the };. For whatever reason, tikz is very whitespace-sensitive. I deleted the blank line and it worked fine.

Comment: Blank lines in TeX are paragraph breaks.  You wouldn't want a paragraph break in the middle of a matrix, so it's not allowed.  TeX makes a guess at what you meant, but guesses mostly incorrectly.